# Dynamic font support in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

By using bellow code i am provide Dynamic font this way and when i change font in **ipad settings -> Disply & brightness -> text size -> change size**  it will work perfect which i want

```
lbl.font = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium))
lbl.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```

But i have problem in `UINavigationController`, `UINavigationBar` title text,`UIBarButtonItem` text font size not change.

I have try to set font this way but it not work

```
    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: UIFont.mediumFont(ofSize: 18)),]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

How we can set **`adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory`** in `UINavigationController` ?

[image]

Comment: Well I think you are not supposed to do this. You should let the text size how it is for titles and buttons in UINavigationController. For reference, check Native apps.